# Passing data from broadcastreceiver to UI

Tags: android

I have implemented brodcast reciever to listen to messages from google messaging service, I am trying to pass data from Broadcastreceiver to mainactivity I am using handler to pass the data when I send message from server to Phone it results in force close I am not able to get the log also.

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   String mes;
   String action;
   Handler handler;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(context));
    Log.d("regid", "notification received" );
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    action = intent.getAction();
    mes = extras.getString("message");
    Log.d("regid", "" + mes);
    Toast.makeText(context,mes,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    Message messobj = handler.obtainMessage();
    b.putString("message",mes);
    messobj.setData(b);
   handler.sendMessage(messobj);

}}
```

and in main activity:

```
  handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public  void handleMessage( Message msg){
            String msg1 = msg.getData().getString("message");
            if(msg1 != null){
                text.setText(msg1);
            }
            else {
                text.setText("message not received");
            }
        }
    };
```

when I send the message from the server app force closes.

Comment: Its is hard to find the problem without having the Log messages.

Comment: i am not able to get the log

Comment: Remove all the filters to the Log messages.

Comment: May be because handler is null at handler.obtainMessage().

Comment: Handler handler is null check the log, you suppose to find the null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are'nt initilizing the handler field at the broadcast receiver therefore you are suffering a NullPointerException.
There are a lot of ways to do this:

- **EventBus** - If u aren't familier with this library then u should use [link](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)
- **Create an interface** (example: onMessageShow) and let the MainActivity implement it and pass it to the receiver at the constructor, then at the point where u want the to do the work call the interface listener and it will do the work.

> Notice: **onReceive** is being called on the **UI thread**.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much i was wondering how to communicate form a non ui thread

Comment: Ok, but at this case you are on the UI thread. As i mentioned there are a few ways, the two that i've explained are my favorites.